# Different counter for equations inside environment

Tags: equations, environments, counters, tcolorbox

Let's say I have a `tcolorbox` environment called `note`. Is there a way for equations that appear inside this environment to automatically assume a different counter from those outside? With automatically I mean without defining a new equation environment?

Here's an example (no second counter implemented):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{note}[1][]{%
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{black},
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt,
    frame hidden,
    left=1ex,right=1ex,
    fonttitle={\bfseries},
    coltitle={black},
    title={Note:\ },
    attach title to upper,
    #1}

\begin{document}

Outside text followed by equation.
\begin{equation}
    a = b.
\end{equation}

\begin{note}
    Inside text followed by equation.
    \begin{equation}
        b = c.
    \end{equation}
\end{note}

More outside text followed by conclusion.
\begin{equation}
    a = c.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you be interested in using the same counter, but *prefixed*, e.g;, after equation (1) in the main body, an equation inside a note would be numbered (N2)?

Comment: @Bernard Not really. I need the counters outside the environment to run irrespective of any equations inside environments that might be nestled in between.

Comment: I've posted my code (which rests on Christian Hupfer's). AS you can see, it's enough to define a counter associated to equations in this environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a variant based on the preceding code, which should work in any environment and is compatible with `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond, ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{chngcntr, mathtools,}
\usepackage{framed,  etoolbox, cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{framedeqn}
\AtBeginEnvironment{framed}{\let\c@equation\c@framedeqn\def\theequation{N\theframedeqn}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some outside text followed by conclusion in \cref{noteeq:a}:  %
\begin{equation}
    a = c.
\end{equation}

Outside text followed by equation:
\begin{equation}
    a = b. \label{eq-out}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{framed}
\noindent\textsc{Note 1: }\\
 An equation inside some environment,  different from \cref{eq-out,noteeq-b}:
 \belowdisplayskip = 0pt
\begin{align}
  x = y \label{noteeq:a}
\end{align}
\end{framed}
Outside text followed by equation:
\begin{equation}
    c= d.
\end{equation}

\begin{framed}
\noindent\textsc{Note 2: }\\
 Another equation inside the same environment:
 \belowdisplayskip = 0pt
\begin{align}
  z = t \label{noteeq-b}
\end{align}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also very nice! `cleveref` compatibility is certainly a bonus as I use it a lot. In that regard, you and Christian both over-delivered.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for a whole new `equation` environment, only a `fake` counter has to be established which is used inside by saying

```
\let\c@equation\c@fakeequation
```

Remember, that `\c@foo` is the internal representation macro of the counter `foo`, so this means that unless specified otherwise all operations to the `equation` counter are actually done with `fakeequation`, so this trick should be used in a group rather, which is done by the `code=....` option in the definition of `\newtcolorbox`.

`cleveref` works out of the box too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{fakeequation}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter

\let\latex@theequation\theequation
\newtcolorbox{note}[1][]{%
  code={\let\c@equation\c@fakeequation\renewcommand{\theequation}{N\latex@theequation}},
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{black},
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  left=1ex,right=1ex,
  fonttitle={\bfseries},
  coltitle={black},
  title={Note:\ },
  attach title to upper,
  #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{fakeequation}{100}

Outside text followed by equation.
\begin{equation}
    a = b.
\end{equation}

\begin{note}
    Inside text followed by equation.
    \begin{equation}
        b = c. \label{innerref}
    \end{equation}
\end{note}

More outside text followed by conclusion.
\begin{equation}
    a = c.
\end{equation}

\begin{note}
    Inside text followed by equation.
    \begin{equation}
        b = c. \label{secondref}
    \end{equation}
\end{note}


The inner equation is \eqref{innerref} and \cref{secondref}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Splendid! Don't you think the appearance of the counter should be modified, say  prefixed like this `(N1)`, to avoid ambiguities in cross references?

Comment: @Bernard: There might be confusion with this scheme of course. I'll change

Comment: Meanwhile, I thought it would be more general to patch the counter with `\AtBeginEnvironment`.  I've just tested:  it works nicely with an environment like `framed`, which doesn't have a powerful keys system like `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @Bernard: I've used this trick on some occasions already. It's quite basic and should work for most occurences, also in a patch

Comment: Thanks Christian, this works great! @Bernard I'd be interested to see such a solution as well in case you have one ready.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to avoid monkeying with counter names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{savedequation}
\newcounter{tcbequation}
\newtcolorbox{note}[1][]{%
  code={%
    \setcounter{savedequation}{\value{equation}}%
    \setcounter{equation}{\value{tcbequation}}%
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{N\arabic{equation}}%
  },
  after={%
    \setcounter{tcbequation}{\value{equation}}%
    \setcounter{equation}{\value{savedequation}}%
  },
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{black},
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  left=1ex,right=1ex,
  fonttitle={\bfseries},
  coltitle={black},
  title={Note:\ },
  attach title to upper,
  #1,
}

\begin{document}

Outside text followed by equation.
\begin{equation}\label{A}
    a = b.
\end{equation}

\begin{note}
    Inside text followed by equation.
    \begin{equation}\label{B}
        b = c.
    \end{equation}
\end{note}

More outside text followed by conclusion.
\begin{equation}\label{C}
    a = c.
\end{equation}

\cref{A}, \cref{B}

\end{document}
```

[image]